# How use Jquery checkbox value and Class attribute set arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How use Jquery checkbox value and Class attribute set arrays

it is what i wanted. 
when all **checkbox** are **checked**.
jquery alert ( 
        parameter ===> A ===> value ===> a1,a2,a3,a4,a5 
        parameter ===> B ===> value ===> b1,b2,b3,b4,b5 
        parameter ===> C ===> value ===> c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 
)

when all **checkbox** are **unchecked**

jquery alert ( 
        parameter ===>  ===> value ===>  
        parameter ===>  ===> value ===>  
        parameter ===>  ===> value ===>  
) 
 or  
 jquery alert ( 
           parameter ===> A ===> value ===>a1,a2  
) 

 or  
 jquery alert ( 
           parameter ===> B ===> value ===>b1,b2  
) .......... etc

how can do this

**html**

```
<div class="checkboxes">
 <input type="checkbox" value="a1" class='A'/> a
 <input type="checkbox" value="a2" class='A'/> a
 <input type="checkbox" value="a3" class='A'/> a
 <input type="checkbox" value="a4" class='A'/> a
 <input type="checkbox" value="a5" class='A'/> a
 <input type="checkbox" value="a6" class='A'/> a
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkboxes">
 <input type="checkbox" value="b1" class='B'/> b
 <input type="checkbox" value="b2" class='B'/> b
 <input type="checkbox" value="b3" class='B'/> b
 <input type="checkbox" value="b4" class='B'/> b
 <input type="checkbox" value="b5" class='B'/> b
 <input type="checkbox" value="b6" class='B'/> b
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkboxes">
 <input type="checkbox" value="c1" class='C'/> c
 <input type="checkbox" value="c2" class='C'/> c
 <input type="checkbox" value="c3" class='C'/> c
 <input type="checkbox" value="c4" class='C'/> c
 <input type="checkbox" value="c5" class='C'/> c
 <input type="checkbox" value="c6" class='C'/> c
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

$('.checkboxes input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    var mycheck = new Array();
    var param = $(this).attr('class');

    $(".checkboxes input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            mycheck.push( $(this).attr("value")); 
        }
    });
    alert("value ===> " + mycheck + " ===> parameter ===> "+param);
  });
 });
```

## [SEEDEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/518y6513/3/)

Comment: Do you not already have that? Apart from that you first have value, and parameter next?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have them grouped by parameter?

Comment: Tip: Your `.each()` iterator is returning just `:checked` items, so you don't need this within the loop: `if ($(this).is(':checked'))`

Comment: Tip #2: You could actually simplify it by using `$.map()` instead: [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

Comment: This comment: _yes sir, give me jfiddle answer_ will bring you plenty of downvotes. We're not here to code for you. We're here to help you with your code.

Comment: why my question are downvotes ... so so bad

Comment: @JavaEagle  https://jsfiddle.net/518y6513/9/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/518y6513/10/

Comment: i wanted you answer upvotes

Comment: @JavaEagle You should actualy just delete this question, since it will be of no helpt to anyone else.

Comment: why should remove my question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as  :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.checkboxes input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        var A = new Array();
        var B = new Array();
        var C = new Array();
        var param = $(this).attr('class');
        $(" input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('A')) {
                A.push($(this).attr("value"));
            }
            if ($(this).hasClass('B')) {
                B.push($(this).attr("value"));
            }
            if ($(this).hasClass('C')) {
                C.push($(this).attr("value"));
            }
            });
            //alert("value ===> " + mycheck + " ===> parameter ===> "+param);
            alert("parameter ===> A ===> value ===>" + A +
                  "\nparameter ===> B ===> value ===>" +B +
                  "\nparameter ===> C ===> value ===>" +C 
                 );
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" value="a1" class='A'/> a
    <input type="checkbox" value="a2" class='A'/> a
    <input type="checkbox" value="a3" class='A'/> a
    <input type="checkbox" value="a4" class='A'/> a
    <input type="checkbox" value="a5" class='A'/> a
    <input type="checkbox" value="a6" class='A'/> a
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" value="b1" class='B'/> b
    <input type="checkbox" value="b2" class='B'/> b
    <input type="checkbox" value="b3" class='B'/> b
    <input type="checkbox" value="b4" class='B'/> b
    <input type="checkbox" value="b5" class='B'/> b
    <input type="checkbox" value="b6" class='B'/> b
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" value="c1" class='C'/> c
    <input type="checkbox" value="c2" class='C'/> c
    <input type="checkbox" value="c3" class='C'/> c
    <input type="checkbox" value="c4" class='C'/> c
    <input type="checkbox" value="c5" class='C'/> c
    <input type="checkbox" value="c6" class='C'/> c
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a little bit more dynamic, which uses [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and [`.toArray`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/):

```
$('.checkboxes input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {

    var output = '';

    // loop over your .checkboxes, which all seem to share the same classname
    $('.checkboxes').each(function() {
        // find the classname
        var param = $(this).find('input').attr('class');
        // map your checked checkbox values to an array
        var mycheck = $(this).find(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
            return ([$(this).val()]);
        }).toArray();
        // only when there are values to show in this array
        if (mycheck.length) {
            // build the output string
            output += "value ===> " + mycheck + " ===> parameter ===> " + param + "\n";
        }
    });

    // output the string
    alert(output);

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh7das5v/)

Answer (score 0):

Another one that's a bit more cleaner in terms of code and data structure using [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

```js
function createObject() {
    var arr = {};
    $(".checkboxes").each(function() {
        var $inputs = $(this).find(" > input");
        arr[$inputs[0].className] = $inputs.map(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                return this.value;
            }
        }).get();
    });    
    alert (JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4));
}

//createObject();

$(":checkbox").on("change", createObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
 <input type="checkbox" value="a1" class='A'/> a
 <input type="checkbox" value="a2" class='A'/> a
 <input type="checkbox" value="a3" class='A'/> a
 <input type="checkbox" value="a4" class='A'/> a
 <input type="checkbox" value="a5" class='A'/> a
 <input type="checkbox" value="a6" class='A'/> a
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkboxes">
 <input type="checkbox" value="b1" class='B'/> b
 <input type="checkbox" value="b2" class='B'/> b
 <input type="checkbox" value="b3" class='B'/> b
 <input type="checkbox" value="b4" class='B'/> b
 <input type="checkbox" value="b5" class='B'/> b
 <input type="checkbox" value="b6" class='B'/> b
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkboxes">
 <input type="checkbox" value="c1" class='C'/> c
 <input type="checkbox" value="c2" class='C'/> c
 <input type="checkbox" value="c3" class='C'/> c
 <input type="checkbox" value="c4" class='C'/> c
 <input type="checkbox" value="c5" class='C'/> c
 <input type="checkbox" value="c6" class='C'/> c
</div>
```